# How to get data from object in an array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an object of the following:

`const fruit = { type: [apple, orange, grape, kiwi], amount: [apple, orange, apple, grape];`

it means that there is 4 types of fruit which is apple, orange, grape, and kiwi and there are 2 apples, 1 orange, and 1 grape.

how do I print using for loop something like this:
apple : 2
orange : 1
grape : 1
kiwi : 0

Comment: What is the format of your data? Why are the amounts not numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below.

```js
// Your Input
const fruit = {
  type: ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'kiwi'],
  amount: ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape'],
};

// Counting array items and store as an object
const fruitCount = fruit.amount.reduce(
  (acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item]: (acc[item] ?? 0) + 1,
  }), {}
);

// Printing items according to type from input
fruit.type.map(e => {
  console.log(e, fruitCount[e] || 0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get the output

```js
const fruits = {type: ["apple", "orange", "grape", "kiwi"], amount: ["apple", "orange", "apple", "grape"],};
const fruitsMap = new Map();

Object.keys(fruits).forEach((key) => {
  fruits[key].forEach((fruit) => {
    if (fruitsMap.has(fruit)) {
      fruitsMap.set(fruit, fruitsMap.get(fruit) + 1);
    } else {
      fruitsMap.set(fruit, 1);
    }
  });
});

let fruitsStr = "";
for (const [key, value] of fruitsMap.entries()) {
  fruitsStr += `${key} : ${value} `;
}

console.log(fruitsStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruit = { type: ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'kiwi'], amount: ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape']};
let types = {};
fruit.type.forEach(elem=>{
    //making a js object of fruit types
    types[elem] = elem;
});
let amounts = fruit.amount;
let result={};
Object.keys(types).forEach(type=>{
    //reset the amounts per fruit.
    result[type] = 0;
})
amounts.forEach(fruit=>{
    //every accurance of a fruit, plus one to the value.
    result[fruit]++;
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. The first output is an object. The others are strings.

```js
// Input
const fruit = {
  type: ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'kiwi'],
  amount: ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape'],
};

// Create an Object to store fruit information
const fruitInfo = new Object()
fruit.type.forEach(item => fruitInfo[item] = 0);
// Output: {apple: 0, grape: 0, kiwi: 0, orange: 0}

// Count fruit
Object.keys(fruitInfo).forEach(key => {
    fruit.amount.forEach(item => {
    if (item == key) {
        fruitInfo[key]++;
    }
  })
});
console.log(fruitInfo); // Log raw data (an object)

// ------ APPENDIX -------
// Log fruit one by one (strings)
Object.keys(fruitInfo).forEach(key => console.log(`${key}: ${fruitInfo[key]}`));
```